# Changing gem fork in Docker project causes GitHub CI testing to fail

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rubygems, git-fork, github-ci

Rails project with Docker-compose.  I needed to change the fork of a gem repository.  It is simply a new fork, everything else is identical. So the source of the gem was changed in the Gemfile:

From: `gem 'csv-importer', gh: 'fork-name/csv-importer', branch: 'custom-branch'`

To: `gem 'csv-importer', gh: 'new-fork-name/csv-importer', branch: 'custom-branch'`

The project seems to work fine locally with the new forked gem.  But when pushed to GitHub, the GitHub CI fails with this error message:
`rake aborted!
Bundler::GitError: The git source https://github.com/new-fork-name/csv-importer.git is not yet checked out. Please run 'bundle install' before trying to start your application`

Some research was indicating that changes to the Dockerfile might fix it,  but no go.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine3.9

ARG bundle_without=development:test

RUN apk add --no-cache \
  # Bundler needs it to install forks and github sources.
  git \
  # Gems need the dev-headers/compilers.
  build-base \
  # PostgreSQL adapter needs the development headers.
  postgresql-dev=~11 \
  # Rails SQL schema format requires `pg_dump(1)` and `psql(1)`
  postgresql=~11 \
  # Install same version of pg_dump
  postgresql-client=~11

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./
RUN bundle install --jobs=10 --no-cache --without=$bundle_without

EXPOSE 3000

CMD bundle exec puma -v --config=- --port=3000
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like the `Gemfile.lock` file was the culprit.  Will possibly delete the question if this is not useful for anyone.

Comment: What was wrong with the lock file and what did you do to solve the problem?